# In "Download build artifacts" task, how do I specify "Build pipeline" as variable value?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to specify "Build pipeline" value in download build artifacts task as variable value like "$(Pipeline)".

But the classic editor does not allow to do so.

[image: adding build pipeline as variable]

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you can't use a variable in this input when you use the Classic Editor, but you can use a variable if you use a YAML pipeline:

```
variables: 
  buildName: TestBuild

steps:
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: 'xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'
      pipeline: '$(buildName)'
      buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
      downloadType: 'single'
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
      artifactName: test
```

If you still want to use the Classic Editor you can "hack" the system by export the build to json:

[image]

Open the json and replace there the value with a variable, then import the build:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can we see a more complete screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish? There are two tasks for this, "Download Build Artifacts" and "Download Pipeline Artifact", and neither is giving me any trouble with a variable reference:

[image: Download Build Artifacts]

[image: Download Pipeline Artifact]

Comment: He trying to put a variable when the build is "specific run" and then in "build pipeline" field. not in "Artifacts name" field.